# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Story with 'id'=):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been looking at other people's posts about this question. Unfortunately, still a while later I am stuck on it. I understand that a couple of the controller methods cannot find a story with the relevant 'ID' and render that to the views, hence my error.

However, I don't understand how I can edit my controller methods/routing so it can actually find the id of '1,2,3,4 etc'. I believe it is trying to look for a different from of ID. The 'create' and 'show' methods are creating the same error.

Error on screen:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in StoriesController#create 

Couldn't find Story with 'id'=

def find_story
    @story = Story.find(params[:id])
end
```

Here, I have put in ID as the params for the story find method but it isn't finding it. Why?

```
class StoriesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_story, only: [:destroy, :create, :show, :edit, :update]


def index
    @stories = Story.order('created_at DESC')
end

def new
    @story = Story.new
end

def create
    @story = Story.new(story_params)
    if @story.save
        flash[:success] = "Your beautiful story has been added!"
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def edit
end

def update
    if @story.update.attributes(story_params)
        flash[:success] = "More knowledge, more wisdom"
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

def destroy
    if @story.destroy
        flash[:success] = "I think you should have more confidence in your storytelling"
    else
        flash[:error] = "Can't delete this story, sorry"
    end
end

def show
    @stories = Story.all
end

private

def story_params
    params.require(:story).permit(:name, :description)
end

def find_story
    @story = Story.find(params[:id])
end


end
```

My routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

get 'stories/new/:id' => 'posts#show'
resources :stories
devise_for :users
root to: 'stories#index'
end
```

Comment: post full error please

Comment: You are trying to find stroy with id but not passing id in the params THATS THE MAIN REASON

Comment: You said it was create AND show?  Looks like just create from error above, is it also show, and if so, can you give me an example of the route you are using for that, it needs to have an id in it, e.g."/whatever/therouteis/1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to change the ":find_story" to not include the create as that is what is telling it to look for an id, but there is no id when on the create page, you are creating a new one, not finding one that exists

so change the before_action to this

```
before_action :find_story, only: [:destroy, :show, :edit, :update]
```

Your issue with stories is the route you are trying to use.  Show looks for an id, for the same reason I mentioned above, so the route need to be something like

```
stories/show/1
```

where "1" is the id of the story you want.

Comment: That works,, thanks! If I go on /stories/show it gives me the similar error 'ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in StoriesController#show ' 'Couldn't find Story with 'id'=show'

Comment: needs to be "stories/show/:id", so "stories/show/1" for example

Comment: You don't do `stories/show` that's not a RESTful route.  Do `stories/1` to show story with id 1, etc...

Comment: so configure my routing to be 
get 'stories/show/:id' => 'posts#show' ?

Comment: no that is linking to the post controller, with the resources in your route you should have the route available already, if you type in rake routes in the terminal you should see that route

Comment: If this solved the issue could you accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in StoriesController#create

you have before_action `:find_story` with create method which is trying to find `Story` but there is no `:id` in params

So you need to remove `:create` action from the list of `before_action` and change it to

```
before_action :find_story, only: [:destroy, :show, :edit, :update]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same problem.

```
@table = Table.find(params[:id])

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find Table with 'id'=12222: 
app/controllers/tables_controller.rb:27:in `edit'

Sol: Try this query
@table = Table.find_by_id(params[:id])
```